# Update takes the data of a deleted row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am surely missing something here but this problem has been extremely annoying. First I deleted a row from database using a serial number :-

```
db.delete(database.Table1, "serial=?", new String[]{serialnumber});
```

Then I wanted to use the deleted serial number to **only** update another row's serial number  (serial2) using:-

```
values.put(database.serial,serialnumber); //inserting my deleted serial

db.update(database.Table1, values, "serial=?", new String[]{serial2});
```

Instead of updating **only** the serial it took all the deleted data of the first row, replacing all the data of the second row. It happened only with serial and I don't know how the first row's data came back when it was already deleted.

the serial is not a primary key or auto increment, it's an INTEGER.

Comment: Apparently, the first row was not deleted. Is the serial numer a number or a string?

Comment: A String but contains numbers ...whats confusing is that I know It must've not been deleted properly but Iam sure the row was deleted because i fetch the data using the serial and show the rows in list-view after the delete The row disappears from the list view.Yet the other row's values all change.